# Doctrine findBy month and year

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

(Hi),
I need to find all my objects from a date formated at (mm-yyyy), problem is than formated date are string and I can't compare dateTime objects and strings.

> Could not convert PHP value '03-2019' of type 'string' to type 'datetime'. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime

I show you my code :

```
/**
 * @Route("/month/{date}", name="monthly_resume", methods={"GET"})
 * @param RentReleaseRepository $rentReleaseRepository
 * @param $date
 * @return Response
 */
public function monthlyCalcul(RentReleaseRepository $rentReleaseRepository, $date)
{
    if (substr($date, 0, 7) === 'Janvier') {
        $date = str_replace('01-', 'Janvier ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 7) === 'Février') {
        $date = str_replace('02-', 'Février ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 4) === 'Mars') {
        $date = str_replace('03-', 'Mars ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 5) === 'Avril') {
        $date = str_replace('04-', 'Avril ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 3) === 'Mai') {
        $date = str_replace('05-', 'Mai ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 4) === 'Juin') {
        $date = str_replace('06-', 'Juin ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 7) === 'Juillet') {
        $date = str_replace('07-', 'Juillet ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 4) === 'Août') {
        $date = str_replace('08-', 'Août ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 9) === 'Septembre') {
        $date = str_replace('09-', 'Septembre ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 7) === 'Octobre') {
        $date = str_replace('10-', 'Octobre ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 7) === 'Novembre') {
        $date = str_replace('110-', 'Novembre ', $date);
    } elseif (substr($date, 0, 8) === 'Décembre') {
        $date = str_replace('12-', 'Décembre ', $date);
    } else {
        throw new LogicException('OK ... So ... There is a problem');
    }

    $currentDate = new \DateTime();
    $currentDate = $currentDate->format('m-Y');

    $rentRelease = $rentReleaseRepository->findBy(
        [
            'userRentRelease' => $this->getUser(),
            'date' => $currentDate, // the problem is here
        ]
    );

    //TODO calcul algorithm

    return $this->render('resume_page/month.html.twig', [
        'date' => $date
    ]);
}
```

To create my date I did it:

```
$rentRelease->setDate(new \DateTime());
```

Of course there is an issue to this problem, but I don't have any idea about how to resolve it... Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: make everything first of the month and compare

Comment: ok, but what about hours minutes and secondes ?

Comment: $currentDate->format('m-Y')  return a string. You can't use a string to compare with datetime in your findBy, send your DateTime object without formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$currentDate = $currentDate->format('m-Y');` to `$currentDate = $currentDate->format("Y-m") . "-01 00:00:00";`

but you must define your logic code like

```
    // use $year and $mounth as parameter !
    if (!is_numeric($year)) $year = date('Y');
    if (!is_numeric($mounth)) $mounth = date('m');

    $currentDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $year . "-" . $mounth.'-15');
    $start_mounth = $currentDate->format("Y-m") . "-01 00:00:00";
    $end_mounth = $currentDate;
    $end_mounth->add(new DateInterval('P01M'));
    $end_mounth = $end_mounth->format("Y-m") . "-01 00:00:00";
```

and in your logic sql you define

```
    ->andWhere('e.date BETWEEN :start AND :end')
    ->setParameter('start', $start_mounth )
    ->setParameter('end', $end_mounth)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing this:

```
 $rentRelease = $rentReleaseRepository->findBy(
    [
        'userRentRelease' => $this->getUser(),
        'date' => $currentDate, // the problem is here
    ]
);
```

To this

```
$startDate = new \DateTime('01-'.$date.' 00:00:00');
$endDate = (clone $startDate)->modify('+ 1 month - 1 second');

$rentRelease = $rentReleaseRepository->createQueryBuilder('rent')
    ->where('userRentRelease = :user')
    ->andWhere('date BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo')
    ->setParameters([
        'user' => $this->getUser(),
        'dateFrom' => $startDate,
        'dateTo' => $endDate,
    ])
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```